# reduce, or explicit recursion?

Tags: coding-style, lisp

I recently started reading through Paul Graham's On Lisp with a friend, and we realized that we have very different opinions of reduce: I think it expresses a certain kind of recursive form very clearly and concisely; he prefers to write out the recursion very explicitly.

I suspect we're each right in some context and wrong in another, but we don't know where the line is. When do you choose one form over the other, and what do you think about when making that choice?

To be clear about what I mean by reduce vs. explicit recursion, here's the same function implemented twice:

```
(defun my-remove-if (pred lst)
    (fold (lambda (left right)
                  (if (funcall pred left) 
                      right 
                      (cons left right)))
          lst :from-end t))

(defun my-remove-if (pred lst)
    (if lst
        (if (funcall pred (car lst))
            (my-remove-if pred (cdr lst))
            (cons (car lst) (my-remove-if pred (cdr lst))))
        '()))
```

I'm afraid I started out a Schemer (now we're Racketeers?) so please let me know if I've botched the Common Lisp syntax. Hopefully the point will be clear even if the code is incorrect.

Comment: Bear in mind that most CLs will not do tail-call optimization, therefore the common idioms in CL are different, and usually biased against these kind of recursion-based loops.  (And BTW, some Schemers became more specifically Racketeers, some didn't.)

Comment: Which of today's CL implementations worth their name do NOT do tail-call optimization under the right optimization settings?

Comment: In 2006, according to <http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Lisp/comp.lang.lisp/2006-08/msg02122.html>, at least SBCL, ECL, CLISP, GCL, Lispworks, and Franz supported it in their compilers.  From simple googling, it looks like Corman and Clozure do, as well.  I can't find info on Scieneer but it appears to be another CMUCL fork so I'm guessing it likely does.  I can't find info for ABCL but it looks like it probably does not.

Comment: The caveat is that tail call optimization is not _required_ by the standard.

Comment: Of course, the CL standard does not require any specific optimizations, or even a compiler at all, IIRC.  (Scheme is unusual in requiring it, and not just among Lisps.)  If you need a particular performance characteristic, you need to test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a choice, you should always express your computational intent in the most abstract terms possible.  This makes it easier for a reader to figure out your intentions, and it makes it easier for the compiler to optimize your code.  In your example, when the compiler trivially knows you are doing a fold operation by virtue of you naming it, it also trivially knows that it could possibly parallelize the leaf operations.   It would be much harder for a compiler to figure that out when you write extremely low level operations.

Comment: Is that a typo of "the least abstract"?  The rest of the writing seems to suggest you think being more specific (ie., less general/abstract) is better.

Comment: @huayuan: No, I clearly mean "most abstract".  Fold is more abstract than a bunch of detailed hand-coded recursive code.

Comment: That is an unusual perspective.  I'll let others decide whether this is a more conventional way to see it: the class of problems that can be solved by fold/reduce may also be solved using recursion, but not vice versa (eg., naturally we'd not use fold for tree traversal); hence recursion, being suitable for a larger class of problems, is more general than fold.  Using fold to solve a problem provides clue/additional information to the reader that the problem belongs to that specific class, thus conveys the intent better.  From this point of view, fold is more specific than recursion, not less.

Comment: Three-state, seven symbol Turing machines are more general than recursion, but I wouldn't suggest coding with one. You don't want your reader or your compiler guessing what you are doing, because it has to reason about what all those low level details are trying to accomplish (e.g., what the tape in your Turing machine is doing). "Abstract" means "less detail". The purely recursive version has way too much detail; it tells you way too much about how to accomplish the computation, to the point of being a specific implementation of fold.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to take a slightly-subjective question and give a highly-subjective answer, since Ira already gave a perfectly pragmatic and logical one.  :-)

I know writing things out explicitly is highly valued in some circles (the Python guys make it part of their "zen"), but even when I was writing Python I never understood it.  I want to write at the highest level possible, all the time.  When I want to write things out explicitly, I use assembly language.  The point of using a computer (and a HLL) is to get it to do these things for me!

For your `my-remove-if` example, the reduce one looks fine to me (apart from the Scheme-isms like `fold` and `lst` :-)).  I'm familiar with the concept of reduce, so all I need to understand it is figure out your `f(x,y) -> z`.  For the explicit variant, I had to think it for a second: I have to figure out the loop myself.  Recursion isn't the hardest concept out there, but I think it is harder than "a function of two arguments".

I also don't care for a whole line being repeated -- `(my-remove-if pred (cdr lst))`.  I think I like Lisp in part because I'm absolutely *ruthless* at DRY, and Lisp allows me to be DRY on axes that other languages don't.  (You could put in another `LET` at the top to avoid this, but then it's longer and more complex, which I think is another reason to prefer the reduction, though at this point I might just be rationalizing.)

I think maybe the contexts in which the Python guys, at least, dislike implicit functionality would be:

- when no-one could be expected to guess the behavior (like `frobnicate("hello, world", True)` -- what does True mean?), or:
- cases when it's reasonable for implicit behavior to change (like when the `True` argument gets moved, or removed, or replaced with something else, since there's no compile-time error in most dynamic languages)

But `reduce` in Lisp fails both of these criteria: it's a well-understood abstraction that everybody knows, and that isn't going to change, at least not on any timescale I care about.

Now, I absolutely believe there *are* some cases where it'd be easier for me to read an explicit function call, but I think you'd have to be pretty creative to come up with them.  I can't think of any offhand, because `reduce` and `mapcar` and friends are *really good* abstractions.

Comment: +1 for the explanation and specific discussion of my examples.

Also, it's funny that you say Python people like to write things out explicitly. It's generally true, but in this case, I'm the Python guy and my friend who prefers the explicit recursion is a Lisp hacker whose current day job is implementing parsing expression grammars for the Guile interpreter.

Comment: To say Pythonistas like explicitness is not the same as to say that they like to write things out explicitly. We consider the features of Python to be explicit. It's not a contradiction to use Python abstractions according to their intent and consider them to be explicit.

Answer (score 4):

In Common Lisp one prefers the higher-order functions for data structure traversal, filtering, and other related operations over recursion. That's also to see from many provided functions like REDUCE, REMOVE-IF, MAP and others.

Tail recursion is a) not supported by the standard, b) maybe invoked differently with different CL compilers and c) using tail recursion may have side effects on the generated machine code for surrounding code.

Often, for certain data structures, many of these above operations are implemented with LOOP or ITERATE and provided as higher-order function. There is a tendency to prefer new language extensions (like LOOP and ITERATE) for iterative code over using recursion for iteration.

```
(defun my-remove-if (pred list)
   (loop for item in list
         unless (funcall pred item)
         collect item))
```

Here is also a version that uses the Common Lisp function REDUCE:

```
(defun my-remove-if (pred list)
  (reduce (lambda (left right)
            (if (funcall pred left) 
                right 
              (cons left right)))
          list
          :from-end t
          :initial-value nil))
```